# Data Auding/Validation report

Tags: sql, regex, validation

I am trying to create a report that will highlight data entry errors in my database (this is a vendor supplied database, so I can't add validation into the entry forms).  I'm working with contact data, so all the basic fields you would expect first name, last name, cell, home, fax, email, etc. etc.

What we want to do is create a report that will compare each field in the database and check it against a regex.  If a record contains a field that does not pass regex validation, report the entire record and highlight the offending field.

I've created a sql query to compare each field against a regex expression, but I'm drawing a blank on how to display the results back to my end users.

Any ideas or examples out there????

**I should also ad that we want to be able to print these results out in addition to viewing them on screen.

Comment: Do you display any other query results to your users?  What method do you use?

Comment: This is the first report of many - so not yet.  Next report will be similar in function but based on customer data.

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation

1. [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)
2. [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)
3. [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

To do the highlighting you'll need to add a class to the item in each row.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these out.  I should also add that we want to be able to print these results out so that a manager can discuss the data entry issues in person.

Comment: You're welcome, once you included some code sample i'll be happy to give you more help.

Comment: @jhoop2002 If you want to be able to print I recommend writing 2 pages, 1 page with it pretty in a grid (sortable, searchable) then the other just plain to "print", with a Print button on the first page.